# Error when using regTermTest from R survey() package and MIResult object

Tags: r, survey, imputation, statistical-test

I'm trying to perform a Wald test on an interaction term in a survey-weighted model with imputed data - see below for a toy reprex.

When I run the last three lines of code with `regTermTest` using syntax modeled directly off the [function documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf) I get the following error: `Error in terms.default(model) : no terms component nor attribute`.

A quick Google search seems to suggest this error means I'm passing an unsupported object type to the function; I read this as perhaps `regTermTest` does not support passing an `MIResult` to `model`. However, it seems that as of [version 3.6](http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/survey/NEWS) of the `survey` package, `regTermTest` supports `MIResult` models? [This page](https://rdrr.io/rforge/survey/src/R/regtest.R) also seems to suggest that as well.

Appreciate any guidance on what I'm doing wrong. Alternatively I could be happy if someone knows how to get p-values on individual model terms from an `MIResult` object (e.g. like is shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70745526/understanding-regtermtest-from-the-survey-package) for a regular `model` object).

```
# load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)
library(mi)
library(mitools)

# load data on school performance included in survey package
# documentation available here: https://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/html/api.html
data(api)

# remove problematic variables that are unnecessary for this example
apisub <- apiclus1 %>% select(-c("name", "sname", "dname", "cname", "flag", 
                                 "acs.46", "acs.core"))

# create and update variable types in missing_data.frame
mdf <- missing_data.frame(apisub)
mdf <- change(mdf, "cds", what = "type", to = "irrelevant")
mdf <- change(mdf, "stype", what = "type", to = "irrelevant")
mdf <- change(mdf, "snum", what = "type", to = "irrelevant")
mdf <- change(mdf, "dnum", what = "type", to = "irrelevant")
mdf <- change(mdf, "cnum", what = "type", to = "irrelevant")
mdf <- change(mdf, "fpc", what = "type", to = "irrelevant")
mdf <- change(mdf, "pw", what = "type", to = "irrelevant")

# summarize the missing_data.frame
show(mdf)

# impute missing data
imputations <- mi(mdf)

# create imputation list to pass to svydesign
imp_list <- complete(imputations, m = 5)

# create complex survey design using imputed data
dsn <- svydesign(id = ~dnum, 
                 weights = ~pw, 
                 data = imputationList(imp_list), 
                 fpc = ~fpc)

# subset the survey design to remove schools that did not meet both targets 
# just as an example of subsetting
dsn_sub <- subset(dsn, both == "No")

# specify analytic model  
anl <- with(dsn_sub, 
            svyglm(api99 ~ enroll + meals + avg.ed*ell, 
                   family = gaussian(),
                   design = dsn
                   )
            )
# combine results into a single output
res <- MIcombine(anl)  

# perform wald test for main and ixn terms
regTermTest(res, ~meals)
regTermTest(res, ~avg.ed:ell)
regTermTest(res, ~avg.ed*ell)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't figure out how to do this with `regTermTest` but I learned that you can run the following to run a global test for interaction instead:

```
library(aod)

> aod::wald.test(Sigma = vcov(res),
+                b = coef(res),
+                Terms = 6)
Wald test:
----------

Chi-squared test:
X2 = 0.031, df = 1, P(> X2) = 0.86
```